# How to decrease number of links in this Script by assing a single Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, redirect

Any Javascript Expert There how help me in this script ?

Actually i am a template designer, i create free and premium templates, my free templates include non-removal footer links, which means user will have to keep the footer link for my template.

Come to main point.

here is my script:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("credits");

    setInterval(function() {     // check every 2 seconds 

    if (e == null) {            // if div is removed then redirect
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/"
    }


                               // if div is  hidden with css visibility then redirect

    if ($(e).css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }

                            // if div is display none then redirect

    if ($(e).css('display') == 'none') {
        document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }


                               // if div is hidden with css collapse then redirect
    if ($(e).css('visibility') == 'collapse') {
        document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }

    }, 2000) // close time function

    e.setAttribute("href", "http://www.example.com/");
    e.setAttribute("ref", "dofollow");
    e.setAttribute("title", "Blogger Templates");
    e.innerHTML = "Example"

}
</script>

<a id="credits"></a>
```

Now, if you see the above script, you will observe that it uses 4 http://www.example.com links except `e.setAttribute("href", "http://www.example.com/");`. whilte i want to do some tricks with this JS so that i uses only one time the main link `http://www.example.com` by assign variable and use that instead of full link.

Like this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("credits");

    setInterval(function() {     // check every 2 seconds 

    if (e == null) {            // if div is removed then redirect
        window.location.href = "e"
    }


                               // if div is  hidden with css visibility then redirect

    if ($(e).css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        document.location.href = "e";
    }

                            // if div is display none then redirect

    if ($(e).css('display') == 'none') {
        document.location.href = "e";
    }


                               // if div is hidden with css collapse then redirect
    if ($(e).css('visibility') == 'collapse') {
        document.location.href = "e";
    }

    }, 2000) // close time function

    e.setAttribute("href", "http://www.example.com/");
    e.setAttribute("ref", "dofollow");
    e.setAttribute("title", "Blogger Templates");
    e.innerHTML = "Example"

}
</script>
```

As you see i added **"e"** variable instead of full link but it does not work, it is redirecting to example.com/e which is not valid. i gave you the idea. so make it possible

So, how to do this ? i already assign "e" variable to my main link.

Please share the full coding with me thanks.

Comment: The variable `e` points to a DOM element, which is fine when you're checking the css attributes and so on, but not fine when you are trying to set the current page location to the same element (instead of some kind of url).  Is the url stored in `e.href`?

Comment: My main question is that, to use variable name instead of that full link, yes my redirection should be only goes to http://www.example.com i also add this tag in my html body at the footer area.  <a id="credits"></a>

Answer (score 1):

Ok. First off, "e" is NOT a variable, it is a string literal. Which means you are literally assigning "e" to document.location.href. Additionally, you have previously created a variable named "e", and assigned it the value of a DOM element with the ID "credits."

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but the following might help:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {

  var e = document.getElementById("credits");
  var redirect = 'http://www.example.com';

  // check every 2 seconds
  setInterval(function() {      

    // if div is removed then redirect
    if (e == null) {
      window.location.href = redirect
    }  

    // if div is  hidden with css visibility then redirect  
    if ($(e).css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
      document.location.href = redirect;
    }

    // if div is display none then redirect
    if ($(e).css('display') == 'none') {
      document.location.href = redirect;
    }

    // if div is hidden with css collapse then redirect
    if ($(e).css('visibility') == 'collapse') {
      document.location.href = redirect;
    }

  }, 2000) // close setInterval

  e.setAttribute("href", redirect);
  e.setAttribute("ref", "dofollow");
  e.setAttribute("title", "Blogger Templates");
  e.innerHTML = "Example"

}
</script>
```

Comment: You are awesome awesome awesome, this is what exactly what i wanted. you did this man.

Comment: Awww shucks. =} Glad I could help. Feel free to mark this as the accepted answer, or whatever, so I can get the points. Since I've linked my StackOverflow profile to my portfolio site, and I'm using their jobs page, potential employers are looking at my ranking these days.

Answer (score 1):

The `"e"` you've added isn't a *variable*, it's a *string*. Setting it as the `href` attribute will just set `href="e"`, which will link you to `/e` on the current domain.

You need to use either:

```
var siteName = "http://www.example.com";

// Wherever you need it:
document.location.href = siteName;
```

Or just use the `OR` operator, `||`, to combine your `if` statements. You can repeat this for all cases.

```
if (e == null ||
  $(e).css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
    document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
}
```

Other than that, what you're trying to do is really a bad practice. I'd advice against it.

Comment: thanks man your first condition is what i wanted the same, thanks for your piece of code.